# Hadoop: start-dfs.sh permission denied(publickey,password)

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am installing Hadoop on my system, and SSH login in without key works fine:

[image]

but I cannot start Hadoop:

[image]

Is there anyone can help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hadoop services don't have to run as root - try running the start_dfs.sh script without using sudo.

Comment: Hi Sakuram! I have the same problem! Have you found a solution? I tried execute it without the sudo statement, but the same error appears!